# Master thesis biochemistry

Tags: publications, thesis, masters, biology, bioinformatics

I am looking for a topic for my master's thesis in the field of biochemistry, but there is a problem, how can I make sure that the topic I have chosen is not repeated? Because there are many sites, journals, etc.  Should I search all of them to make sure that the research topic is new?

Comment: Do you have an advisor?  Helping with this should be part of your thesis advisor's job.

Answer (score 1):

One part of most theses is a literature review. This should probably be begun before you settle completely on a topic to avoid repeating work already in the literature. There will be a period of refinement as you close in on the topic, depending on what you find in the literature.

Few people already know enough about any topic to write a thesis without a review of the literature. Part of the process of extending knowledge is obtaining a solid sense of what is already known.

In some cases the lit review will cause you to drop or modify the topic and certainly any hypotheses you make. The review might lead to choices of methodology.

But, yes, you need to do a search. Both an advisor and an academic librarian can help. The advisor should be aware of the obvious things to avoid and the librarian can help you find relevant material on a given topic.